# Is this contract just sending eth to scammers address

Tags: etherscan, scam, arbitrage, bot

`https://ethbotarbitrage.com/code`

Trying to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a fraud contract.

Do not believe those who say that you can do such operations very easily. Because it's not easy at all

Whenever I see such a function, I immediately realize that it is a scam.

```
function startExploration(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }
```